# How to fill nan values with rolling mean in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, mean

I have a dataframe which contains nan values at few places. I am trying to perform data cleaning in which I fill the nan values with mean of it's previous five instances. To do so, I have come up with the following.

```
input_data_frame[var_list].fillna(input_data_frame[var_list].rolling(5).mean(), inplace=True)
```

But, this is not working. It isn't filling the nan values. There is no change in the dataframe's null count before and after the above operation. Assuming I have a dataframe with just integer column, How can I fill NaN values with mean of the previous five instances? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did put inplace=True in the fillna call

Comment: hmm, are you possibly setting values on a copy of the `df`? - what is `var_list`? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: var_list is a list that contains column names.

Comment: have you tried running the op without the `var_list` selector?

Comment: yes, I did try it without var_list.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work:

```
input_data_frame[var_list]= input_data_frame[var_list].fillna(pd.rolling_mean(input_data_frame[var_list], 6, min_periods=1))
```

Note that the `window` is `6` because it includes the value of `NaN` itself (which is not counted in the average). Also the other `NaN` values are not used for the averages, so if less that 5 values are found in the window, the average is calculated on the actual values.

Example:

```
df = {'a': [1, 1,2,3,4,5, np.nan, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, np.nan] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)
print df

      a
0   1.0
1   1.0
2   2.0
3   3.0
4   4.0
5   5.0
6   NaN
7   1.0
8   1.0
9   2.0
10  3.0
11  4.0
12  5.0
13  NaN
```

Output:

```
      a
0   1.0
1   1.0
2   2.0
3   3.0
4   4.0
5   5.0
6   3.0
7   1.0
8   1.0
9   2.0
10  3.0
11  4.0
12  5.0
13  3.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The mistake I made was that I did not put min_periods=1 parameter in the rolling().mean(). Also, thank you for letting me know that the window size should be 6.

Comment: Any idea of how can I achieve this row-wise? I mean replacing null value(say df.iat[i,j]) with average of df.iat[i,j-2], df.iat[i,j-1], df.iat[i,j+1], df.iat[i,j+2]

Comment: But what if I want to keep filling up NaN values with the previous rolling mean? This only fills NaN values correctly when there's only one NaN in between data rows.

Comment: Not totally clear the question, so maybe better if you post a new one But maybe what you need is to create a list of index with nan and using it in a variable for the rolling windows in the function

Answer (score 13):

`rolling_mean` function has been modified in pandas. If you fill the entire dataset, you can use;

```
filled_dataset = dataset.fillna(dataset.rolling(6,min_periods=1).mean())
```

Comment: But what if I want to keep filling up NaN values with the previous rolling mean? This only fills NaN values correctly when there's only one NaN in between data rows.

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use interpolate()

```
df = {'a': [1,5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 5, np.nan] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)
print(df)


df['a'].interpolate()
```

Comment: `interpolate` and `rolling average` both are techniques to fill nan values. But these two are two different things. rolling average calculates averages/sum of the adjacent missing values. And interpolate fill nans between two values by assuming there is a steady growth or decline in between of these two points.

Comment: I wanted to fill nan values with mean of the previous 5 instances. Interpolation is a different thing.